# Allowing end user to change order of list graphically

Tags: java, list

I wish to display a list of items and allow the user to change the order of the items in a graphical interface. Clearly they could just be provided with a box next to each item and allow them to enter a number but that's not very elegant. Is there a list component that provides this facility?

Comment: "a graphical interface" made in which technology? Presuming Swing, JList already has support for drag & drop, you just need to wire it up.

Comment: You could use an up/down button which changes the index of the selected item in a JList